# Symfony2 doctrine2 array data is available and works in Twig file but rendered blank page

Tags: mysql, symfony, twig

I'm getting datas from MySQL database but not display in rendered TWIG file. in TWIG file, I execute Twig's dump() function It works, all datas displayed but TWIG is empty.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $yorumlar = $em->getRepository('SiteSiteBundle:Yorum')->find($id);

    if (!$yorumlar) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException($id . ' nolu Yorum bulunamadı!');
    }

    return $this->render('SiteSiteBundle:Default:liste.html.twig', array(
                'yorumlar' => $yorumlar
    ));
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your twig file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just acces to your propertie. Using var_dumpt, print_r or any dump function in a managed entity could crash or marke verry slow you php server because it will try to dump you entity doctrine and all his dependancies maybe the container...

```
{{ yorumlar.yourPorpertie }}
```

Comment: this is works. it was single data. single row data doesn't need FOR statement.